# Adding Multiple Markers Google Maps Ionic with AddMarkerCluster

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm trying to add multiple markers to a map using `ionic 3.19.0` with `cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.1.1`.

I did manage to add like three markers using `AddMarker()` but when I try to add more than 5 it just breaks. I couldn't get the error and sometimes the call to the api where the latitude and longitude falls because it has more than 100 positions.

With `addMarkerCluster()` it returns the latitude and longitude correctly but it doesn't appear on map.

I'm looping through the array of positions that I retrieve from the server.

This is my service doing requests to the server:

```
export const test_data: TrackerPositionData = {

  lat: null,
  lng: null,

}


getPositions(ids): Observable<TrackerPositionData[]>{


    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/positions', {
      ids: ids

    }, {
      responseType:'text'
    })    
    .map(res => {


      res = JSON.parse(res)

      var data = [];

      for(let i=0;i<res.length;i++){

        test_data.lat = res[i][this.key.LATITUDE][this.key.VAL];
        test_data.lng = res[i][this.key.LONGITUDE][this.key.VAL];

        data.push([
          {lat: test_data.lat, lng: test_data.lng},
        ])
      }

      return data;


    })
    .catch((err, caught) => caught)
  }
```

this is where I'm showing positions on map

```
showLastPositionsOnMap(){
    //ids is an array of ids containing a position, each
      for (let i=0;i<this.ids.length; i++){
        console.log('started_positions for');
        this.getEvent.getPositions(ids[i])
        .subscribe(res=>{
          //res[1][2] is where my latitude and longitude are, they return fine in the console

          let latitude = res[i][0][this.key.LATITUDE_M];
          let longitude = res[i][0][this.key.LONGITUDE_M];

          let userPosition: LatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


          let options = {
            markers:  [{
              position: userPosition,
              name: "Test",
              address: "Test",
              phone: "999-999-999",
              icon: "www/assets/img/pin.png"
            }],
            icons: [
              {icon: "www/assets/img/pin.png", min: 2, max: 10},
              {icon: "www/assets/img/pin.png", min: 11, max: 30},
              {icon: "www/assets/img/pin.png", min: 31},
         ],

          }

            console.log('added_marker');
            console.log('started_positions adding marker'+i);

            return this.map.addMarkerCluster(options)

        },(err)=>{
          console.log(err)
        });
      }

}
```

I'm creating google maps in my constructor with this code:

```
this.plt.ready().then(() => {

        let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
          camera: {
            target: {
              lat: this.phoneLat,
              lng: this.phoneLong
            },
            zoom: 10,
            tilt: 0
          }
        };

        console.log('about to create map');
        this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

        this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {

          this.showLastPositionsOnMap();
          this.map.refreshLayout();
        }).then(()=>{
          let options = {
            icon: {
              url: "www/assets/img/icon.png",
              size: {
                width: 40,
                height: 40
              }
            },
            position: userPosition,
            map: this.map,
            title: dev.model+' is here'
          }
          this.map.addMarker(options);
        })
});
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: `"www/assets/img/icon.png"` should be `"assets/img/icon.png"`

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I had to use `www/`first to get it working. As i've said,it is working when I add 3 or 4 using `addMarker`, but not when I use `addMarkerCluster`

Comment: Giving `www` in path means `http://localhost/www/assets/img/icon.png`.

Comment: Check out the demo code of marker cluster. https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo/blob/master/src/pages/marker-cluster/marker-cluster.ts